# Winforms DataGridView bound to List<T> - Show only specified properties of T

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and I'm binding it directly to a generic List of a custom class, no BindingSource intermediary. This custom class has a number of public properties and I want my dataGridView to display only some of those properties.

I've created datagridview columns for the custom class properties I'm  interested in, and set their `DataPropertyName` to the class properties names. But the gridview fetches all the properties from its source and displays them.

Is there anyway to display only those properties I'm interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
public int SomeProperty{get;set;}
```

in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) = false, then manually populate columns. or use 
`Browsable(false)` attribute in columns which you don't want to show.

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns, right. It's been a while since I've worked on winforms. Thats the property I was looking for. Was looking at the properties window but strangely it's not there.